# How to convert a PDF to a postscript file using pdfbox 2.0

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, postscript

I was able to create a PDF with PDFBox (version 1.8.9) and then convert it to a PostScript file with the following code:

```
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE;
    StreamPrintServiceFactory[] factories =
            StreamPrintServiceFactory.lookupStreamPrintServiceFactories(flavor,
                    DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.POSTSCRIPT.getMimeType());
    if (factories.length == 0) {
        throw new PrinterException("No PostScript factories available");
    }
    PDDocument document = pdfGenerator.getDocument();

    // Attributes are specified by https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
    // see package javax.print.attribute.standard
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
    aset.add(new PageRanges(1, document.getNumberOfPages()));

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePathAndName);
    factories[0].getPrintService(fos).createPrintJob().print(
            new SimpleDoc(new PDPageable(document), flavor, null), aset);
    fos.close();
    document.close();
```

The PDPageable object doesn't seem to be in the PDFBox 2.0 code and I didn't see it specified in the migration document.  How do I convert a PDF file to a PostScript file using PDFBox 2.0?

Thank you

Comment: There is a PDFPageable.

Comment: If you find out the answer to your question, it's helpful to post it as an answer. That way, others can learn from what you found out.

Comment: Thank you.  What I ended up doing was using PDFBox to reading back in the PDF and writing out the post script commands myself using the x/y coordinates that PDFBox read from the PDF.  I didn't want to have to teach myself post script commands but that was the only way that I found that I could create a post script file that was reasonably sized.  The PDPageable class wrote each PDF page as an image so that post script file was many times larger than I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, in [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) the [version 1.18.12 Package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.12/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/package-summary.html) has a PDPageable class, but the corresponding [version 2.0.3 Package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/package-summary.html) does not.

But what you want to to do is convert to a PostScript language document. I think [PDFPrintable](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/printing/PDFPrintable.html) will do that for you.

See this other SO question, [Printing to PostScript with PDFBox produces a massive file, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109841/printing-to-postscript-with-pdfbox-produces-a-massive-file-why), for a code snippet that shows PDFPrintable in use.  I've simplified it a bit and included it below. Does it look familiar to you? :-)

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePathAndName);
StreamPrintService sps = factories[0].getPrintService(fos);
        DocPrintJob dpj = sps.createPrintJob();
        SimpleDoc sd = new SimpleDoc(new PDFPrintable(document, Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE, false), flavor, null);
        factories[0].getPrintService(fos).createPrintJob().print(
                new SimpleDoc(new PDFPrintable(document, Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE, false), flavor, daset), aset);
fos.close();
document.close();
```